# Get The Name Field Class Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, helper

```
public class ViewModel_Index
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [UIHint("_Date")]
    public DateTime bd { get; set; }
    [UIHint("_EnumRadioButton")]
    public Gender sex{ get; set; }
}
```

File _EnumRadioButton.cshtml

```
@model Enum
@{
    List<SelectListItem> LstT = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Array ev = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType());
    foreach (Enum item in ev)
    {
        LstT.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Sample.Service.CustomExtension.EnumExtension.ToDescription(item),
            Value = item.ToString()
        });
    }
    @Helpers.RadioButtonList(Model.GetType().Name , LstT)
}
```

File Helpers.cshtml

```
@helper RadioButtonList(string groupName, IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> items)
{
    <div class="RadioButtonList">
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            @item.Text
            <input type="radio" name="@groupName" value="@item.Value"
            @if (item.Selected) { <text> checked="checked" </text>    } />
        }
    </div>
}
```

index

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <button type="submit">send</button>
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test(ViewModel_Index a)
{ 
    return View();
}
```

view source

```
<div class="RadioButtonList">
    زن<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Woman"/>
    مرد<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Man"/>
    هیچکدام<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Non"/>
</div>
```

File _EnumRadioButton.cshtml
prablem:
name radio must be same name field

radio Name="gender" 
field Name="sex"

@Helpers.RadioButtonList(**Model.GetType().Name** , LstT)

Comment: You are trying to get the label "Gender" from the model's `Gender sex` property into your radio button helper?

Comment: It appear you wanting to generate a series of radio buttons to select a gender in which case the _"class type"_ has nothing to do with your issue. Whats important is the name of the property and the values of the enum.

Comment: Get the name of the class field
Get the word "sex"

Comment: When the data is sent.
If the radio button is not in the same field names.
The data are not binding

Comment: Field "sex" is not bound